# Correct syntax to HAVING with thinking sphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a query and I want to run the same with thinking sphinx, but I'm having problems with `HAVING` clause. The relevant code is the following:

```
#technology_index.rb
  has taggings.tag_id, :as => :tag_id
  has id, :as => :technology_id

#technology.rb
    search(params[:query],
      with: { tag_id: params[:filter].values.flatten },
      group_by: :technology_id,
      having: "COUNT(`technology_id`)=#{params[:filter].size}"
    )
```

This throws me the following error (new lines in error message are mine):

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting '*' near '`technology_id`)=1 LIMIT 0, 20; 
SHOW META' - SELECT *, groupby() AS sphinx_internal_group, id AS sphinx_document_id, 
count(DISTINCT sphinx_document_id) AS sphinx_internal_count 
FROM `technology_core` WHERE MATCH('fibrosis') AND `tag_id` IN (2) 
AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 GROUP BY `technology_id` HAVING COUNT(`technology_id`)=1 
LIMIT 0, 20; SHOW META
```

The problem is with `having:` clause, because if I remove it, at least the query works.
Is supposed since 2.2.1 beta [`HAVING` is supported](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/11/26/sphinx-2-2-1-beta-and-2-1-3-release-now-available/) (using 2.2.6), [the same for TS 3.1](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/tag/v3.1.0) (using 3.1.2). I couldn't find any info [about use of HAVING](https://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html) in the docs, but if I try something like `having: "COUNT(*)>1"` works so I guess, I'm just invoking it incorrectly. What should be the correct way to use `having:` with TS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that something like `having: "COUNT('technology_id')=#{params[:filter].size}"` is still not supported by sphinx.
Anyway my query worked with `having: "COUNT(*)=#{params[:filter].size}` as I was grouping by `technology_id`.

Comment: Just to be clear its COUNT(column) that isnt supported by sphinx - it doesnt really have concept of NULL in fact. But COUNT(*) works. (ie rather than being a problem with HAVING)